# Google maps for business not connecting

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have integrated Google Maps for business SDK with iOS

But when I run the app now , It gives me following error.

```
ClientParametersRequest failed, 3 attempts remaining (0 vs 5). Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 400.)" UserInfo=0xab79cf0 {data=<CFData 0xab89bf0 [0x2e20ec8]>{length = 145, capacity = 256, bytes = 0x3c48544d4c3e0a3c484541443e0a3c54 ... 3c2f48544d4c3e0a}}
```

and then

```
Your key may be invalid for your bundle ID:com.xxxxx;
```

I searched a lot but everywhere i found to check bundle identifier , I checked it several times, it is correct,  but the problem isn't solved yet.

please help me on the same

Comment: Did you register your app as a web app or client app?

Comment: i had not registered my app

Comment: does it need registering, than how to register it please explain

Comment: Please read [Google Maps SDK for iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#getting_the_googke_maps_sdk_for_ios)

Comment: for registering  goto [Google APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/?noredirect)